# find method of moments estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Consider a random sample of size  of  from a distribution with its pdf given by
()={
(1/)^(−(−)/ ),      >

0,        ℎ

Find the MMEs of  and .

I found the MME of  as barX(n) -  using integration to find E(X), which is +. Can I use this to find that of , which is barX(n)-?

Btw do you think I am on the correct approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your density is difficult to read and probably wrong

Comment: If you are trying to estimate two parameters using the method of moments, then you should be looking at effectively two different moments, such as the mean and variance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can calculate $E(X)=\int_{\alpha}^{\infty} x\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x-\alpha}{\theta}}dx=\alpha+\theta$ and $E(X^2)=\int_{\alpha}^{\infty} x^2\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x-\alpha}{\theta}}dx=\alpha^2+\theta^2+2\alpha\theta$ and $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)=\theta^2$
 So we have $\tilde{\theta}=\pm\sqrt{\overline{X^2}-\overline{X}^2}$ since $\theta > 0$ Therefore  MME of  $\theta$ is $\tilde{\theta}=\sqrt{\overline{X^2}-\overline{X}^2}$and for MME of $\alpha$, we can find above equations $\tilde{\alpha}=\overline{X}-\tilde{\theta}=\overline{X}-\sqrt{\overline{X^2}-\overline{X}^2}$

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me back then. I got an A in the class.